# Redirection is leading me to Page not found error in Django

Tags: python, django

Project urls.py includes app urls. I am using HttpResponseRedirect to get Likes posted on site. I am not trying to call for template so this is why not using render_to_response. My app view is:

```
def like_article(request, article_id):
    if article_id:
        a = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
        count = a.likes
        count += 1
        a.likes = count
        a.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('articles/get/%s' % article_id)
```

My app urls.py reflects likes redirection like this:

```
    url(r'^like/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article.views.like_article'),
```

My parent "articles" HTML file extended from base says:

```
    <p>{{article.likes}} people liked this article</p>
```

My single article page extended from base.html shows:

```
    <p><a href="/articles/like/{{article.id}}">Like</a></p>
```

Please advise.

Comment: You'd better use `{% url [name] [parameters] %}` in your template while `reverse` function in your view to create urls.

Comment: Have you checked if your like_article() function executes as desired until return statement!

Comment: Yes it executes with no errors. Problem is to get likes posted on website. However after clicking like it leads to me 404. When I go back on the page it shows the like is recorded.

Comment: Please post your entire `urls.py`

Comment: from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns=patterns('',
    url(r'^all/$', 'article.views.articles'),
    url(r'^get/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article.views.article'),
    url(r'^language/(?P<language>[a-z\-]+\d+)/$', 'article.views.language'),
    url(r'^create/$', 'article.views.create'),
    url(r'^like/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article.views.like_article'),
)

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use {% url [name] [parameters] %} in your template while reverse function in your view to create urls.

In your question, I think the problem is the url router doesn't match.

See:

```
<p><a href="/articles/like/{{article.id}}">Like</a></p>
```

And:

```
 url(r'^like/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article.views.like_article'),
```

It seemed the `/article` prefix doesn't appeared in you url.

Answer (score 0):

Have you mapped the url - `articles/get/article_id`, i.,e added a similar pattern in urlpatterns (ex: `url(r'^get/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article.views.get_article', name='get_article'),`) tuple, to which you redirected the users!

If yes, then have you created a proper view for it!

Comment: I did it to call for singly article display.

Comment: It exactly says url(r'^get/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article.views.article'),

Comment: If that wasn't included I guess it shouldn't had let me choose single article from "articles.html". I can browse between articles but can't get "Likes" redirected.